# lldb attaching to coreaudiod prohibited

Tags: macos, debugging

Trying to:
1. Stop coreaudiod
2. Start LLDB and "attach --name coreaudiod --waitfor"
3. Start coreaudiod
I always get: "error: attach failed: lost connection"

I've checked that 127.0.0.1 localhost is in the /etc/hosts file.

I've also disabled system integrity protection with "csrutil disable" in Recovery OS:

```
System Integrity Protection status: enabled (Custom Configuration).

Configuration:
    Apple Internal: disabled
    Kext Signing: disabled
    Filesystem Protections: disabled
    Debugging Restrictions: disabled
    DTrace Restrictions: disabled
    NVRAM Protections: disabled

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.
```

But to no avail.. help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I jumped to conclusion, after doing "csrutil disable" in Recovery OS mode, attaching in Xcode seems to work just fine. Also, using the "Pre-action" in the debugging scheme, I can stop/start coreaudiod before trying to attach to it making debugging a single-click!